# Syntax highlighting for unimplemented languages by introducing aliases of lang-none

Tags: discussion, feature-request, syntax-highlighting

Today I "struggled" with misleading syntax highlighting of markdown code examples, the problem was that using `lang-none` changes the colouring so that a previously unaffected markdown example looked different now, but the examples are related. I [searched for the correct language code or tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184108/238205) for markdown, bot found nothing. Then I looked into [Issues · google/code-prettify · GitHub](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/issues) and there seemed nothing pending.

I finally used `lang-none` <sup>[see 5th rev here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17028463/revisions)</sup>, but I realized that a better solution would be to have language synonyms for this purpose. Wouldn't this be easier, if at all possible?

Comment: I'm not sure what you suggest. You link to an answer. The prettifier takes any language hints from the tags on the question, in this case [html](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/html/info) which has `default` as its syntax highlighter. If that doesn't fit for the posts overruling the language is your only option.

Comment: @rene I mean there is currently no `lang-md` or `markdown` so preventing from displaying markdown code wrong can only be done by using `lang-none`. For languages that should exist and most probably will exist sometimes a `lang-md` implemented by `lang-none` would by handy. That's what I wanted to suggest/discuss...

Comment: Are you suggesting that currently non-existing languages (e.g. `lang-md`) should default to `lang-none` instead on `default` (which I assume is what currently happens)?

Comment: @Cai yes, provided that they are listed as aliases somewhere (to prevent lots of spellings for the same thing). This would probably save some intermediate edits and decouples from waiting for implemented support. The only downside (from my POV) is that you cannot be sure *that* an anticipated language will really be supported some day.

Comment: Fair enough, I don't post enough code that doesn't have existing highlighting to know but I'd have guessed that the default would be better than none in most cases.